# ssh by a python cgi script is not working

Tags: python, linux, apache, ssh, cgi

I have a couple of things to ask.I am getting following error while trying to ssh remote host from a python CGI.

```
Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'.
Failed to add the RSA host key for IP address '17.172.221.39' to the list of known hosts (/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

Is this becuse its not taking my password or is it because of apache eing user and ssh is not allowed...

How to make sure ssh happens without having to do ssh key initiation for this on all hosts.

how can i Run a cgi script as root user and not as apache user.
I have to run few scripts only as root.I cant use SuExec etc.Please provide the work around for these 2 issues i am facing

Comment: You can `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null host` to write the host key to a dummy location instead

Comment: I guess its working...but failing at the step where we enter password.

Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '17.172.221.39' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive).

Can i know how to give password for ssh from python cgi script or browser.

Comment: And since apache being the user,will it take my password?

Answer (score 0):

Web server process is owned by apache user not as root.

1. Make sure that apache user have password less access to other server
2. SELinux should be disabled

Refer : http://wccandlinux.blogspot.in/2016/07/how-to-run-ssh-command-from-apache.html

Comment: ....is der a way I can do without SSH stup for Apache....and can I run CGI script as root from web browser??

Comment: You can try this . But it can cause vulnerabilities : http://askubuntu.com/questions/116144/how-do-i-run-apache-as-root

Comment: ....I am geeting below error...not sure reason for this...

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

can you help in figuring it out